# Are there organized surfing day trips from Bordeaux?

Tags: france, tours, seasonal, surfing

I am eyeing a weekend trip to Bordeaux as flights are cheap and was thinking to go surfing for a day while there, given that some surfing spots are relatively close.

I found that I could take [the bus](http://transgironde.gironde.fr/ftp/FR_document/FH%20702_ETE.pdf) [to Lacanau Ocean](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bordeaux/LACANAU-Oc%C3%A9an) and choose among the surfing schools there, but I would not mind joining an organized day trip from Bordeaux for more ease of mind.

- Are there any day trips from Bordeaux to surfing spots along the Atlantic coast (not necessarily Lacanau)? I am looking for transport from Bordeaux, equipment rental, ca. 2h of lessons and possibly some food included.
- Are the surfing conditions favorable in July / August?

I am a quasi-noob to surfing (have done one weekend long ago) and would like to join a beginners course e.g. in the morning and then try a bit on my own in the afternoon ideally.

The second question is since I found some [sources](http://www.surfing-waves.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=140) stating that while courses are offered in summer, waves are "the least consistent".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options here. As you said, you could just go along the coast and ask any surfing school, I'm sure they'd offer you what you're looking for.

Here are a few options if you want to ease your mind:

- [citysurf](http://www.citysurf.fr/tarifs/) offers a discovery session for 55€: every week-end day from april to november; shuttle from Bordeaux; 2 hours sessions; time depending on tide; age and level groups; spot depends on weather conditions
- [lacanau surfing school](http://www.ecole-surf-lacanau.com/tarifs-reservation.php) lets you book and pay online, so you can do that and take the bus

As for the surfing conditions, I've never had to complain but that's not something we can control :)

Comment: +1 from me, thanks! Does the offer from citysurf include the possibility to use the material also in the afternoon or just for the duration of the course? Have you ever taken their day trips and how long approximately would it take (i.e. by which time more or less is one back to Bordeaux)?

Comment: Bordeaux > surfing spots shouldn't take much more than 2h, depending on which spot they chose and on the traffic (the spots extend from Soulac to Hendaye). I've never taken their day trips so I can't answer your question but you should ask them directly: contact@citysurf.fr !